# R sum list of data.frame with almost same structure

Tags: r

Here is my question,

I have a list of data.frames. It's produced by same piece of codes with different data.

All of the data.frames looks like

US 100 (not guarantee to exist in another data.frame because data is different)
CA 50
...

Is there any fast/neat way to sum over all the data.frames?

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8940086/1863950).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure whether I have understood your problem correctly, but here a possible solution:

Try to put all your dataframes in a list, e.g., `your_list=list(df1,df2,...)`
Then use `total_df=do.call(rbind,your_list)` to combine all dataframes (row-wise).

After that you can use `ddply(total_df,"country",function (x) sum(x$value))` to aggregate the data. Here, I have assumed that `US` and `CA` stand for entries in a `country` column and `100` and `50` for entries in a `value` column.